# How to make checkbox/slider persistent?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, persistence

Till now I've created apps that stored mainly objects ecc in an SQLite database.
But how would I make a checkbox/slider persistent?

Example:
The user goes in the settings and checks "Use Dark mode"
How would I make it that the checkbox remains checked after closing the app, so the user wouldn't have to check the dark mode everytime he opens my app? SharedPrefernces?

Comment: Yes, you will have to store the `Checkbox` state somewhere, `SharedPreferences` is a good option, then when the user comes back to this screen you will read the value from `SharedPreference` and update the `Checkbox` state.
Some things to look into are: `checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(..)` - to listen to changes every time the Checkbox is changed and `checkbox.setChecked(..)` to update the state of the Checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into SharedPreferences then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AndyRes said, you can store simple data like this in shared preferences. This is a simple key value store, ie you store values against a key and can fetch the stored value by providing the key.

Eg

```
getSharedPreferences().edit().putBoolean("my_key", checkBox.isChecked()).apply;
```

Will store the value of the checkbox into a key "my_key". You should change this to something meaningful
You want to put this inside a listener so you save it every time the check state changed either using checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener or onClick of a save button.

When you load the activity you want to retrieve the state and update the checkbox to match ie

```
//the second parameter false is the default value to be used if the key doesn't exist in the store
boolean checked = getSharedPreferences().getBoolean("my_key", false);
checkBox.setChecked(checked)
```

Note that i'm using the function getSharedPreferences() which is a function of Context and can be used in an activity